# Can't open an audio file Where i'm saving some input from Microphone (c#)

Tags: c#, xna, microphone

I tried to get some input from Microphone and to save it into a **.wav/.mp3 file**. I succeeded to get the input from the microphone, and to save it to file too. But I think that there's a problem with the saving, because when i'm trying to open the file manually, i'm encountering an error which says that my media player can't open the file.
If this information is needed, I'm using XNA to get the audio from the Microphone.
My code:

```
byte[] Buffer = new [Microphone.Default.GetSampleSizeInBytes(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000))];
int i = 0;
While(i != Buffer.Length - 1)
{
    microphone.GetData(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length); //With this code i'm getting the input from the Microphone..
    i++;
}
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Program\TestRecord.wav", Buffer); //With this code i'm saving the input in my file.
```

Does anyone know what can be the reason to this problem? I'll be glad for some help with it..

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

While my answer may not be much help, I can't actually add a comment due to my low reputation :(

However, I believe that your problem is you're getting RAW bytes that aren't in any specific format. You need to encode it into the WAV format itself. I would start [here for writing WAV files in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15187/Concatenating-Wave-Files-Using-C-2005). It may not be the whole solution, but it's at least some sort of starting ground for you.

Best of luck; I couldn't find many solutions at all while browsing Bing or Google. However, it could be I wasn't using the best of search terms.

EDIT: I also found another site that might be of interest for you [that talks](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-use-wavefilewriter.html) about using [NAudio](https://naudio.codeplex.com/).